# Auto type a keyword in a website's textbox and submit

Tags: c#, watin

I have a project about automatic accessing to website: www.alexa.com and take the results( traffic rank, page rank)  of a website (inputed in a textbox) to C# code.
Would you tell me how to type a website address in textbox of www.alexa.com page, and press submit automaticaly ? Then how can I take the result???
Please!!!
First, I have a function to access to www.alexa.com page:

```
public void LauchBr()
        {
            string URL = "http://www.alexa.com";

            try
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(URL);
            }
            catch
            (
            System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception noBrowser)
            {
                if (noBrowser.ErrorCode == -2147467259)
                    MessageBox.Show(noBrowser.Message);
            }
            catch (System.Exception other)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(other.Message);
            }
        }
```

Comment: http://www.ichi.co.uk/post/12744611627/getting-an-alexa-rank-programmatically-in-csharp

Answer (score 0):

//Firstly get that text box inside a variable

```
        var inputtextbox = browser.TextField(Find.ByName("CASE"));
        if (!inputtextbox.Exists)
        {
            LogError(c, fileNumber, CommonUtils.Messages.ElementNotFound, ClientID);
            return;
        }
```

//You can use TypeText() or value to type what ever you want.

```
        inputtextbox.Value = "Your Text here.";
        inputtextbox.TypeText("Your Text Here");
```